# C# Application Settings not saving using custom class

Tags: c#, class, settings, appsettings

Here's the class im trying to store

```
 [Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Database", IsNullable = false, Namespace = "http://somesite.com")]

class Database
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]   
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Provider")]
    public DatabaseProvider Provider { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Driver")]
    public string Driver { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DatabaseEntry")]
    public List<DatabaseEntry> SavedEntries { get; set; }

    public Database()
    {
        SavedEntries = new List<DatabaseEntry>();
    }

    public Database(string type, string provider, string driver)
    {

        Name = type;
        Driver = driver;
        Provider = DatabaseProvider.SqlClient;

        Provider = SetProvider(provider);
        SavedEntries = new List<DatabaseEntry>();
    }

    private DatabaseProvider SetProvider(string provider)
    {
        switch (provider)
        {
            case "OleDb":
                return DatabaseProvider.OleDb;
            case "SqlClient":
                return DatabaseProvider.SqlClient;
            default:
                return DatabaseProvider.SqlClient;
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "DatabaseEntry", IsNullable = false, Namespace = "http://somesite.com")]

class DatabaseEntry

{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ConnectionString")]
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "DsnString")]
    public string DsnString { get; set; }

    public DatabaseEntry()
    { }
}
```

Database is the parent class that I'm trying store, anyone see anything wrong?  When I instantiate the class and save it, nothing gets saved.  What gives?

EDIT! The code that is being used to save:

```
if (Settings.Default.SqlDatabase == null) 
   { 
      Settings.Default.SqlDatabase = CreateNewDatabase();
      Settings.Default.Save();
   }

private Database CreateNewDatabase()
{
    Database data = new Database("SQL Server", "SqlClient", "SQL Native Client");
    data.SavedEntries.Add(new DatabaseEntry()
    {
        Name = "Default",
        ConnectionString = @"Hello1",
        DsnString = @"Hello2"
    });
    return data;
}
```

I'm simply just trying to store an instance of a Database class into the AppSettings

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to save the class as xml

Comment: edited original post to show how I'm calling it

Comment: opps I edited it the same time as you did, sorry about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try making the classes `public` - `XmlSerializer` is fussy about that.

However, I seem to recall that the settings code is much more interested in type-converters; you could try writing a `TypeConverter` for it?

Comment: yep that did it, i didn't have them as public.  Thanks alot bud!

Comment: Was it just the accessor that you had to change to Public on it's own or did you have to use TypeConverter as well?

Comment: @Vidar - from Tom's comment, I assume just the `public` did it.

Comment: @Vidar - is it perhaps nested inside another non-public type? Can you define "aint working" - any specific error message?

Comment: The value coming back from the Settings.Default.Foo is always null - and I can't figure out why - I do have a field marked as [NonSerialized()] but I don't think that should have any effect.

Comment: @Vidar - `XmlSerializer` doesn't even look at `[NonSerialized]`. It is impossible to answer without more details (ideally sample code).

Comment: Yep - it should be [XmlIgnore()] I think I need to read up a bit more.